# Does any continuous function attain any value between its minimal and maximal values?

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have continuous function $f(x,y)$.

Let us denote by $M$ and $m$, respectively, the maximum and minimum values of the function. 
Can one state that the function $f(x,y)$ attains any value from the following interval $[m,M]$. If yes, is it true for ever continuous function?

P.S. I think that to address the question one can use Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Yes. This is what the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) says.

Comment: It is true for every continuous function?

Comment: Please read the link.

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it wouldn't be a theorem :-)

Comment: Actually what is the domain of the function? Are you working in connected open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Just a pendantic nitpick: "Suppose we have continuous function f(x,y)" "If yes, is it true for every continuous function?".  If $f$ is a general function with nothing more specific known but that it is continuous, then saying it is true for $f$  is exactly the same thing as saying it is true for every continuous function.  ... or did you mean functions on domains other than $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$, suppose that $f(x_\text{min},y_\text{min})=m$ and $f(x_\text{max},y_\text{max})=M$, then for the continuous function
$$
g(t)=f(x_\text{min}(1-t)+x_\text{max}t,y_\text{min}(1-t)+y_\text{max}t)
$$
$g(0)=m$ and $g(1)=M$. Applying the standard Intermediate Value Theorem to $g(t)$, shows that $f(x,y)$ attains every value between $m$ and $M$.

If the domain is a path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, a similar argument can be made using any path $\gamma$ so that $\gamma(0)=(x_\text{min},y_\text{min})$ and $\gamma(1)=(x_\text{max},y_\text{max})$ and using $g(t)=f(\gamma(t))$.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be path connected: connected is enough: If $D$ is a connected domain of the function, then $f(D)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{ R}$ are the intervals.

Comment: Perhaps an exception should be made for continuous function on unconnected domains?

Comment: @Keen: true, but that uses a different proof (that the continuous image of a connected set is connected). I was just mentioning a result which is a corollary of the one I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The only exception could be if $f^{-1}(M)$ and $f^{-1}(m)$ are not in a connected subset of the domain.

Example if $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\cup [2,3]\times [2,3]\to \mathbb R^2$ via $(x,y) \mapsto x + y$ then $m = 0$ and $M= 6$ but there are no $f(x,y) = 3$.  And, yes, that $f$ *is* continuous on the domain.

However if the $f^{-1}(M)$ and $f^{-1}(m)$ are in a connected or path connected subset of the domain, then the Intermediate Value Theorem states precisely this.

=====

The standard statement of the [Intermdediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is for a continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where the domain is the real numbers.  If $a < b$ then for every value $K$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there is a $c \in [a,b]$ so that $f(c) = K$.

We can extend that to any continuous function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ where $a,b \in S \subset X$ where $S$ is connected. Then for any $K$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ there is a $c\in S$ so that $f(c) = K$.